# Fill space left of a centered fluid max-width div

Tags: css, layout, html

I have a centered div with fluid width, bound by a max-width:

```
#content {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 760px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

I'm having trouble filling the space on the left and right of it due to the max-width property. How do I make also fluid divs to the left and right that will fill the empty space, even when the content div is constrained by the max-width? Preferably in a pure CSS way.

Comment: What do you want to fill the empty space with? If you just want to add background color in the empty space you can nest this div in another div that takes 100% of the width and fill that div with your background color. Else, please let us know what you exactly want to do.

Comment: I'm going to fill the space with a div on each side each having more content.

Comment: max-width: 760px and width: 80% will conflict. What do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: I want all 3 divs to fluidly resize with the window, but I don't want the center one to get too big.

Comment: How small in width can each of 3 divs get?

Comment: I don't have a set number yet, though it would be good if the right div disappeared completely, and the center div stayed the majority of the screen

Comment: Yes, don't use max-width property. How can you fill your width if used this. It is funny, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` with the 80%? Also perhaps use `box-sizing` to ensure the percentage values are treated at their true value.

Potential solution here http://jsfiddle.net/vSRgS/1

Comment: When the min-width is larger than the max-width, the max-width doesn't take effect.